# Calculation In Process for a reactive function

Tags: r, shiny

I have a ShinyApp that has to compute a long process before showing a set of graphs and data. I've put it in a reactive object to perform the operations once and then to switch between the tabs without recalculating.

How can i add a "Calculations in progress" box in each tab when the reactive object is working?

I've tried this, but it is not working or at least i dont know where to put the tags:

https://gist.github.com/withr/8799489

Any help is welcome, here it is an example:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")

shinyApp(
  ui=shinyUI(dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
                           dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
                           dashboardSidebar(
                             sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", 
                                         min = 10000, max = 90000, value = 50000, step = 10000)
                           ),
                           dashboardBody(
                             tabBox(
                               tabPanel("Tab 1", "This is tab number 1", tableOutput("tabData")),
                               tabPanel("Tab 2", "This is tab number 2", plotOutput("tabPlot"))
                             )
                           )
  ))
  ,
  server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    calculate_hist <- reactive({
      cat("Calculating for ",input$obs,"\n")
      if (is.null(input$obs)) {
        dist <- NULL
      }else{
        dist<-numeric()
        for (i in 1:input$obs) dist <- c(dist, rnorm(1))
      }
      cat("Ended\n")
      dist
    })
    output$tabPlot<-renderPlot({
      chist<-calculate_hist()
      if (is.null(chist)){
        return()
      }else{
        hist(chist, breaks = 100)
      } 
    })
    output$tabData<-renderTable({
      chist<-calculate_hist()
      if (is.null(chist)){
        return()
      }else{
        sumdata<-data.frame(n=length(chist),mean=mean(chist),var=var(chist))
        sumdata
      }
    })
  })
)
```

Comment: Have you tried https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/Progress.html ?  This function should do the job.

Comment: Yes, it shows a small popup in the bottomright corner of the screen, I'd like it to appear in the middle, but for now it's the best option I have found

Comment: I've implemented a sort of centre of the screen wait message, but I don't recall where I got the inspiration from and it requires some JS file (maybe I got it from here https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/061-server-to-client-custom-messages Otherwise you could add a modal message (again look into shiny gallery / examples) or, a bit extreme to my taste, here https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/loading-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use use `busyIndicator` function from `shinysky` package and override its css using `inlineCSS` from `shinyjs` package.

Something like this:

```
  library(shiny)
  library(shinydashboard)
  library(shinysky)
  library(shinyjs)

  shinyApp(
    ui=shinyUI(dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
                             dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
                             dashboardSidebar(
                               sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", 
                                           min = 10000, max = 90000, value = 50000, step = 10000)
                             ),
                             dashboardBody(
                               useShinyjs(),

                               tags$body(inlineCSS(list(".shinysky-busy-indicator" = "position: absolute !important; z-index:800; "))),

                               tabBox(
                                 tabPanel("Tab 1", 
                                          busyIndicator(wait = 1000),
                                          "This is tab number 1",
                                          tableOutput("tabData")),
                                 tabPanel("Tab 2", 
                                          busyIndicator(wait = 1000),
                                          "This is tab number 2", 
                                          plotOutput("tabPlot"))
                               )
                             )
    ))
    ,
    server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {

      calculate_hist <- reactive({
        cat("Calculating for ",input$obs,"\n")
        if (is.null(input$obs)) {
          dist <- NULL
        }else{
          dist<-numeric()
          for (i in 1:input$obs) dist <- c(dist, rnorm(1))
        }
        cat("Ended\n")
        dist
      })
      output$tabPlot<-renderPlot({
        chist<-calculate_hist()
        if (is.null(chist)){
          return()
        }else{
          hist(chist, breaks = 100)
        } 
      })
      output$tabData<-renderTable({
        chist<-calculate_hist()
        if (is.null(chist)){
          return()
        }else{
          sumdata<-data.frame(n=length(chist),mean=mean(chist),var=var(chist))
          sumdata
        }
      })
    })
  )
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Great, your example works perfect, an indicator in the middle of the screen, just what I was searching for. I will adapt the code to my app. Thank you!

Comment: If this is what you wanted, could you accept the answer?